# how to stream music to a bluetooth module?

Tags: android, bluetooth, streaming, mp3, interfacing

i have a Bluetooth module and micro controller to decode the music. but i don't know how the music is send serially. i have searched for this problem. but i didn't get anything useful.
i need to make a Bluetooth music player system using micro controller. my aim is to play music wireless. 
i want to know how the mp3 files are sending in a android device. how the song is encoded. and the idea of decoding the data. thank you

my Bluetooth module is HC-05
and i'm using 8051 micro controller

its for my project

Answer (score 0):

Use the AudioTrack.write() method to write music data out to a stream. You can choose the encoding, sample rate, channels, etc. when you create the AudioTrack object. If you are just sending the data over a serial connection you should be able to do whatever you want. If you are sending audio to a headset, it has to be mono, 8000 bps, PCM modulated.

Answer (score 0):

most probably it will be in PCM or PWN at the receiving end i.e Micro controller, connect DAC amplify analog signal it should work.